# How to set a variable in a postgresSQL function, to a computed value from another function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, variables, plpgsql

Im having a bit of trouble figuring this one out.

Essentially id like to bind the computed value of `websearch_to_tsquery('simple', search_term)` to variable `foo`.

A hack would be to just hardcode the `to_tsquery` where needed but i wanted to try and clean up my code a bit.

I am reciving the following error,

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "foo"
LINE 8: foo tsquery := websearch_to_tsquery('simple', search_term);
```

here is my code

```
DROP FUNCTION search_exercises(text);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_exercises(search_term text)
returns setof "Exercise"
language plpgsql
as 
$$
BEGIN
  foo tsquery := websearch_to_tsquery('simple', search_term)
  SELECT * FROM "Exercise"
  WHERE foo @@ document
  ORDER BY ts_rank("document", foo) DESC
END;
$$;
```

I am expecting the `search_exercises(search_term)` function to return a table of `Exercise` ranked descending by `ts_rank` given a `document` and that `tsquery` computed from the input arg `search_term`

Ty!

Related Posts:

[How to set the value of a variable in one function with the returned value from another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646691/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-variable-in-one-function-with-the-returned-value-from)

[Select integer returning function result into variable postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670372/19463936)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a variable before you can use it. Additionally each statement needs to be ended with a `;`

```
as
$$
declare
  foo ts_query;
begin
  foo := websearch_to_tsquery('simple', search_term);
  ...
end;
$$
```

Note that your SELECT also needs a `;` at the end and you need `return query select ...` to return the result of a query.

But you don't really need a variable, you could also do this in a single statement:

```
return query
  SELECT * 
  FROM "Exercise"
  WHERE websearch_to_tsquery('simple', search_term) @@ document
  ORDER BY ts_rank("document", foo) DESC;
```

Comment: Okay. There was so many examples online with the declare omitted. I wasnt sure if it was just a section for setting types, i figured `foo tsquery:= websearch_to_tsquery('simple', search_term);` did the declaration + binding in one step. 

Also, for you 2nd solution, does pgsql (or maybe all sql) automatically infer that `foo` is `websearch_to_tsquery('simple', search_term)` inside of the `ts_rank()` call?